# Does * have different meanings based on the context of its usage?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and confused about two different usages of *. I understand that usage of the * is called *dereferencing* and is used to retrieve the value that the pointer points to.

```
int num = 20;
int *ip;
ip = &num;

print("This is the pointer's address: %p\n", ip);     // bffd8b3c
print("This is the value of the pointer: %d\n", *ip); // 20
```

The way I'm thinking of it is that the * is like an operator where when it is applied to a pointer gives the value *in the context of a print statement*.

Elsewhere, I've seen * used in the following way:

```
void someFunction(int **IP){

    int *anotherIP = NULL;
    *IP = anotherIP;

}
```

If I use the same thinking here, *IP should be the value that IP points to. But it seems that that's not the usage. Rather, it's assigning a local pointer to the pointer that IP points to.

**Correction:** the function is assigning `anotherIP` to the pointer to IP, (i.e. `*IP`); IP (pointer to a pointer) is being dereferenced twice as it's passed into the function (`**IP`).

My question is: Is the meaning of * context dependent? If yes, what contexts should I be aware of in common usage? If not, how am I to understand the examples above?

Additionally, what's the rationale behind using the double asterisks in the function above? I see this used often in functions.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, ignoring when it's used for multiplication, it has two meanings. When used as part of a type it makes the type be a pointer to the base type. When used with a value, it dereferences a pointer.

Comment: @ThomasJager Thanks for your reply. How do the two meanings you mention apply to the example of *IP in the function? I'm not seeing how it would be the definition of a type or dereferencing.

Comment: `IP` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`.  Thus `*IP` is a pointer to an `int`, just like `anotherIP` is.  And `**IP` is the `int` that `*IP` points to.  So it is not correct to say that " it's assigning a local pointer to the pointer that **IP points to."

Comment: I find it useful to reconcile these "two meanings" by thinking of a declaration like `int **IP` as saying that `**IP` is being declared as an `int` (that is, if you deferenece `IP` twice, you get an `int`), which means that `*IP` points to an `int` and `IP` points to that pointer.

Comment: @ScottHunter Ah so I was thinking of `**IP` in the reverse. So the correct way to say it would be that it is assigning `anotherIP` to the pointer to IP, (i.e. `*IP`), where the int itself is passed in via `**IP`? In this case, as you mention above, we are dereferencing twice. I'll make edits to my question.

Comment: @ThomasJager: The use of `*` in a declaration is not different from its use in a dereference expression. In `int *x;`, `*x` refer a potential result of dereferencing `x`, and `int` tells us that that result is an `int`. Thus, because `*x` is an `int`, the declaration says that `x` must be a pointer to an `int`. The design of C declarations is that a “picture” of how a thing will be used is presented, and the declaration says what type of the resulting expression is. So `int y()` says the result of calling `y` will be an `int`, meaning `y` is a a function returning `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't specify declaration, just types in general. When you explicitly cast a value the entire type is within the parentheses. `(int *)` doesn't have that same sense of dereferencing a variable yielding a type.

Comment: @jjkl: No, it is assigning `anotherIP` to the pointer that `IP` points to (where *that* pointer points to an `int`).  The thing that gets passed, `IP`, is the first pointer in the chain.

Comment: an easy way to read a variable (including pointers) declaration is from right to left, so: `int *anotherIP = NULL;` is "anotherIP is a pointer to a int"  And `*IP = anotherIP;` is assigning the data where `IP` points to the contents of the pointer `anotherIP`

Comment: @ThomasJager: Grammatically, a declaration `int *x` is not grouped as `(int *)x`. It is grouped as `int (*x)`. If you do not have that “sense” that it is like a dereference operator in this context, that is because you are not understanding the C grammar. See C 2018 6.7. The *declarator* part of a declaration, which is the `*x` in this case, is separate from the type and other specifiers. Declarators have an grammar like expressions (6.7.6).…

Comment: …  E.g., `int (*x)[]()` declares a pointer to an array of functions. `*` expresses a dereference of that pointer, `[]` expresses a reference to an array element, and `()` expresses a function call. They have similar meanings as in expressions, so they form a picture saying that, when something like `(*x)[]()` is used in an expression, it will be an `int`. In a cast as in `(int *)`, there is a unique position where an identifier could be, and the `*` is effectively expressing a dereference of that identifier.

Comment: When you define `int* x, y;` only `x` is a pointer, `y` is not. It means the same as `int *x, y;` but the latter is more clear.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm with you on the first part. For the second part, should I think of it as `int (**IP)` (as per @EricPostpischil's comment)? With this in mind, IP has to resolve to an int and so, given the double asterisks, must be a pointer to a pointer. With regards to `*IP`, we are dereferencing a pointer to a pointer, which gives us the pointer to the int. Additionally, it seems there is an inconsistency; if we had `void someFunction(int *IP){ }`, we use `IP` when referencing the pointer to the int and not `*IP` (It just depends on whether what's passed in is `**IP` or `*IP`?)

Comment: @jjkl: If the parameter is `int *IP`, then `IP` is a pointer to an `int` and you have to pass a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry my question wasn't clear. To confirm my understanding, I was asking whether we are applying the same approach of dereferencing when we have `void someFunction(int **IP){ }` and when we have `void someFunction(int *IP){ }` where in the first, in the function body, we get the the pointer to the int by dereferencing `IP` using `*IP`. In the latter, in the body of the function, we simply use `IP` to get the pointer to the int but use `*IP` now to get the int value?

Comment: @jjkl: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First, in C the declaration of a variable should look like its access.
Meaning the real value of the pointer to a pointer to an int, ist the int value, hence you access it with `int value = **IP`.

You see double pointers often in functions, because it allows you to allocate space for the values you return.

A single pointer will be passed by value to the funktion, if you change it in the function the caller will not see the change.

Answer (score 1):

In a *declaration*, the unary `*` indicates that the thing being declared has pointer type:

```
T *p;       // p has type "pointer to T"
T *p[N];    // p has type "array of pointer to T"
T (*p)[N];  // p has type "pointer to array of T"
T *p();     // p has type "function returning pointer to T"
T (*p)();   // p has type "pointer to function returning T"
```

The subscript `[]` and function call `()` operators have higher precedence than unary `*`, so an expression like `*p[i]` will be parsed as `*(p[i])`; you're dereferencing the result of `p[i]`.  If `p` is a pointer to an array of something, then you have to write `(*p)[i]` - you need to dereference `p` and than subscript into the result.

You can have multiple levels of indirection:

```
T **p;           // p has type "pointer to pointer to T"
T ***p;          // p has type "pointer to pointer to pointer to T"
T *(*p)[N];      // p has type "pointer to array of pointer to T"
T *(*(*p)())[N]; // p is a pointer to a function returning a pointer
                 // to an N-element array of pointer to T
```

In an *expression*, the unary `*` operator dereferences the pointer to access the pointed-to object, as in your example.  Again, you can have multiple levels of indirection:

```
int x = 10;    
int *p = &x;    // p stores the address of x
int **pp = &p;  // pp stores the address of p
```

After those declarations, the following are true:

```
**pp == *p ==  x == 10 // all of these expressions have type int
 *pp ==  p == &x       // all of these expressions have type int *
  pp == &p             // all of these expressions have type int **
 &pp                   // this expression has type int ***
```

C declaration syntax is built off the type of *expressions*.  Suppose you had a pointer to an `int` named `p` and you wanted to access that integer value.  You'd write an expression like

```
x = *p;
```

The type of the *expression* `*p` is `int`, so the *declaration* is written as

```
int *p;
```

If you had an array of pointers to `int` named `p` and you wanted to access the integer value pointed to by the `i`'th element, you'd write

```
x = *p[i];
```

Again, the type of the *expression* `*p[i]` is `int`, so the declaration is written as

```
int *p[N];
```

Multiple indirection shows up in two main places:

**You want a function to write to a parameter of pointer type**

Remember that C passes all function arguments by value, so if you want a function to write to a parameter, you must pass a pointer to that parameter:

```
void foo( T *ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_value();  // writes a new value to the thing ptr points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  T value;
  foo ( &value );     // writes a new value to value
}
```

Let's replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`:

```
void foo( P **ptr )
{
  *ptr = new_value();  // writes a new value to the thing ptr points to
}

void bar( void )
{
  P *value;
  foo ( &value );     // writes a new value to value
}
```

As you can see, it works the same way.  We want to update the contents of `value`, so we must pass a pointer to it.  Yes, `value` already has a pointer type, but we need a pointer to `value` *itself* in order to update it.

Remember, if an lvalue expression `x` has type `T`, then the expression `&x` has type `T *`.  Again, replace `T` with a pointer type `P *`, and you'll see that the expression `&x` has type `P **`.

**You want to allocate a jagged array**

Sometimes you want a 2D (or 3D, or higher) array-like structure, but you don't want the rows to be the same size.  The usual way to do that is like so:

```
T **arr = malloc( N * sizeof *arr ); // allocate an array to hold N objects of type T *

if ( arr )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  {
    arr[i] = malloc( M * sizeof *arr[i] ); // allocate an array to hold M objects of type T, where M can vary from row to row
  }
}
```

`arr` points to the first in a sequence of pointers to `T`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware of there are three 'uses' for the asterisk in the C language.

There's multiplication:

```
int result = 3 * 3; /* result == 9 */
```

There's definition:

```
int *pointer_to_result = &result; /* define a pointer to an int, and initialize it with the address of the result variable */
```

And finally for dereferencing:

```
int copy_of_result = *pointer_to_result /* copy_of_result == 9 */
```

What you are seeing with the double asterisk is [a pointer to a pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_pointer.htm). Read up on these. They are a lot of fun.

Comment: `int *pointer_to_result = &result;` is not assignment. It is a definition with initialization. And the meaning of the `*` there is the same as in dereferencing. In that definition `*pointer_to_result` means “the result of dereferencing `pointer_to_result`”, and the definition tell us that that is an `int`. In other words, because “the result of dereferencing `pointer_to_result`” is an `int`, `pointer_to_result` is a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Changed the wording. While i feel you are correct in in the strict sense (that it's both dereferencing), you are still defining a pointer to an int... For me it helps thinking about it as a 'one thing'. :)